# Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 - URL's can't be generated from display name

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We upgraded our solution from Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 to Update 2. Our URL's are generated from display name and that was working fine.

But after upgrading, the behaviour changed to URL generation from item name although ShowConfig.aspx still shows "useDisplayName="true" for .

We're using the following config:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="sitecore">
                <patch:attribute name="addAspxExtension">false</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="useDisplayName">true</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="languageEmbedding">never</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="alwaysIncludeServerUrl">true</patch:attribute>
            </add>
        </providers>
    </linkManager>
</sitecore>
```

Now all links only show a 404. What am I missing?

We tried on an empty solution and it's the same behaviour. So it is a Sitecore bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We contacted Sitecore Support. They introduced a new setting in Update 2 in Sitecore.config.

```
<setting name="ItemResolving.FindBestMatch" value="DeepScan" />
```

This setting needs to be set to:

```
<setting name="ItemResolving.FindBestMatch" value="Disabled" />
```

It was supposed to solve the following bug:

96805: Item could have been unresolved with specific encodeNameReplacement and wildcard/display name resolving logic

This is now registered as a bug with the reference number 105324.

Comment: Is there e way to Track Sitecore-Bugs?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. But using the search on https://dev.sitecore.net/ with the provided reference number showed a result for the release notes of Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 where this bug got fixed.